# Change variable name and apply.daily function in a loop in R

Tags: r, variables

I'm trying to create a loop which creates 49 different files with names

tr79_1_min

tr79_2_min

.

.

.

tr_79_49_min

in which I use the apply.daily() funtion with different name inside each time
(i already have the v1_t_79_84, v2_t_79_84 etc files)

Basically I want to change the 1 into i

[image: Basically I want to change the 1 into i]

I already tried the paste and assign functions but they gave no results

```
for (i in 1:49) {

name1 <- paste("tr79_",i,"_min",sep="")
name11<- paste("v",i,"_t_79_84",sep="")
assign(name1,apply.daily(name11))

}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to CV. This is a question about programming/using R, which is outside the scope of CV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `get` the variable `name11` first.

```
assign(name1, apply.daily(get(name11)))
```